# what does .debug_info mean in a map file where all the object (*.o) files were listed?

Tags: c, mapping

For the same source code the hex files compile to be identical, however the *.elf and *.map files are different only under the `.debug_info     0x00000000    0x294b5` section. Memory addresses are same otherwise.

Comment: same source code means same source files or just same code in another file?

Comment: same source files